# Wifi not Connecting even though it shows the available networks

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 On an Asus x515ja Laptop..with 8  gigs of ram and i5 10th gen and an intergrated gpu

THis issue popped up this morning.

When I was trying to connect to my wifi through the settings present in the top left part.

The menu just flashes(It just removes the wifi option and some other option for a split second) and the options pop back to normal.. It's not a problem with a specific network.. It's doing this on every network I've tried..Tried getting into the settings and connection but still it didn't work..

Would be thankful if someone could lend a hand :)

Comment: Can you try to connect over nmcli? `nmcli connection up id your-connection-name` Maybe only a problem  with the applet.